# Using MultiNonlinearModelFit with complex data

Tags: fitting, complex

This is my first question, I'll try to formulate the problem first.

I have a complex function `f[z]` of a complex argument z which I calculate in Fortran for any z within the unit circle with 10 digits accuracy. Thus, I can generate arrays of data in the form
{{z_1,f[z_1]},{z_2,f[z_2]},...} for any points `|z_i|<1`.

It is known that the function `f[z]` has the Taylor series expansion

```
f[z_]:=Sum[a[i]*(z-z0)^i,{i,0,\infty}]
```

with **real** coefficients `a[i]` which should be bounded for higher `i`.
The location of a real `z0` near the origin is also not known exactly. I truncate the series to some `i<n`, say `n=6` and using a  `MultiNonlinearModelFit`in the form

```
    MultiNonlinearModelFit[data, ComplexExpand[ReIm[f(x+I*y)]], var, {x, y}]
```

where
`data={Ref,Imf}`, `Ref={{x0,y0,Re[f[z]]},...}`,  `Imf={{x0,y0,Im[f[z]]},...}`,

`var` is a **known** good initial guess for `a[i]` and `z0`.

It works quite well but higher coefficients `a[i]` start growing in the fit which is not correct.  My guess is that the Fit treats all points with the same accuracy and it is causing problems for small `|z|`.
Say, if I take the point z=0.01+z0, it should not be used for the calculation of the coefficient a[5,0] because the term

`a[5,0]*(z-z0)^5 ~ 10^(-10)`

which is the data accuracy.
I need somehow to introduce weighted criteria for different data points that the accuracy of `f[z]` for a given `z` is of the order `z^(n+1)` where `n` is the truncation order.

Comment: `MultiNonlinearModelFit` is not a Mathematica function. How have you defined it? When asking questions, provide a concrete example (code and data).

Comment: @BobHanlon I believe the OP is using the [repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit/).

Comment: `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"]` ?

Comment: @bobthechemist - If so, the syntax should be `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][data, ...]`

Comment: Yes, I evaluate a notebook from the repository quoted above. Any hints on how to prevent coefficients of the fit from growing when data points are close to the centre at z0?